Licensing of transitive packages
I have created an C# appliaction, now and want to distribute it. My application uses some Nuget-packages where each package again references some other packages (transitive packages).
As far as i understood correctly, i need to include all licenses from these packages in my binary distribution. Is this right? Or do i only need to add licenses for packages that are directly used by me (as the dependencies of my dependencies are in fact already distributed as source code, therefore should already contain all liceneses required). Did i understand something wrong? How is this typically done?
